# Duplicate Management - Fuzzy Phone detection not Working?

Tags: duplicate-management

I have a duplicate rule where I check for a Fuzzy Mobile or Phone, on the Lead Object.

I have stumbled with a use case where the Phone on Lead 1(*for the sake of the example*) is something like: +49 1234 56789, and the Phone on the Lead 2(*the potential duplicate*) is something like: 01234-56789.

**Tests:**

1 - I tried to have on Lead 2 smth like: 0123456789 -> The duplicate checker doesn't recognise it as a duplicate.

2 - I tried to have on Lead 2 smth like: 049123456789 -> The duplicate checker doesn't recognise it as a duplicate.

3 - I tried to have on Lead 2 smth like: +49123456789 -> The duplicate checker DOES recognise it as a duplicate.

Is this the correct behaviour of the Duplicate Checker, or I am missing something on the capabilities that this standard feature has?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As per Salesforce docs
>
> This process works best with North American
> data.
>
> - International code (exact, 10% of field’s match score)
> - Area code (exact, 50% of field’s match score)
> - Next 3 digits (exact, 30% of field’s match score
> - Last 4 digits (exact, 10% of field’s match score)
>
> Minimum Threshold 80

So Area code must be same which looks different because of formatting thats why your first two didn't match.

[Matching Methods Used in Matching Rules](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=matching_rules_matching_methods.htm&type=5)